# Android how to zip all file selected in one zip file

Tags: android, file, zip

I have one list all files.
My code get all file in device, and select list some file i want to zip in 1 file zip. How to i can zip all file selected in one zip file ?

```
fun getAllDir(dir: File) {
        val listFile = dir.listFiles()
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (i in listFile.indices) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory) {
                    getAllDir(listFile[i])
                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].path.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                        listVideo.add(
                           
                            listFile[i]
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code to zip one file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to zip or extract zip files you can use this `zip4j` library and check out its documentation it will help you https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j

You can also zip a single file and multiple files also using this library

Comment: yes, i am using this library, but when i zip multiple files finish, file zip have not number item. Example i zip 3 file in file zip when zip finish file zip have not 3 item, only is one file zip.
My code:
 ` net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile(path+"/"+nameFileZip+".zip").addFiles(
            listFile
        )`

Comment: it will zip all three files into one zip please check zip file.

Comment: No bro, i only see 1 file zip and this file zip have not 3 file in it

Comment: Check your list may be something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

As alternaive you could check anoterh lib: [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm)

Create (or open existed) zip archive and add some regular files and/or directories

```java
Path zip = Paths.get("filename.zip");
Collection<Path> paths = Arrays.asList(
        Paths.get("/bikes/ducati-panigale-1199.jpg"),
        Paths.get("/bikes/honda-cbr600rr.jpg"),
        Paths.get("/cars"),
        Paths.get("/saint-petersburg.jpg"));
ZipIt.zip(zip).add(paths);
```